# helpme command, cannot find author's voice channel discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

There are bots that you can do !h and the bot types in chat (authors name, need help, @staff, and in which voice channel is the person who need the help)
How could I find the command author's voice channel?
thats what i tried:
(I am trying it on the `on_message` event for now)

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(f'member is in {message.author.voice_channel}')
```

But when I'm running it and typing something in the chat I receive this error:

```py
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ido Shaked\Desktop\citybot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Ido Shaked/Desktop/citybot/citycode.py", line 18, in on_message
    print(f'member is in {message.author.voice_channel}')
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you exactly what's wrong - a `Member` does not have a `voice_channel` attribute. You have to get it via `message.author.voice.channel`

Comment: i replaced this and now it types me this error:
`
 Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ido Shaked\Desktop\citybot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Ido Shaked/Desktop/citybot/citycode.py", line 18, in on_message
    print(f'member is in {message.author.voice.channel}')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channel
 `

Comment: If the user is not in a voice channel, `member.voice` will return `None`. You can use
`if member.voice:` to check if a member is currently connected to a voice channel.